# Getting Wrong Output in mysql and jdbc

Tags: jdbc, mysql-error-1064

```
public void Deposite() throws Exception
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bank";

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","admin");

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Enter your A/c no. : " );
        acNo = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        String sql = "SELECT Name,Ac_No,Balance FROM CUSTOMER WHERE Ac_No=?";
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setInt(1,acNo);

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next())
        {
            String name = rs.getString("Name");
            int acNo = rs.getInt("Ac_No");
            float bal = rs.getFloat("Balance");

            System.out.println("    "+name+"        "+acNo+"        "+bal);
        }
        System.out.println("Current Bal : "+bal);

        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Enter Deposite Amt : ");
        amt = Float.parseFloat(br1.readLine());

        bal = bal + amt;
        //System.out.println("Current Bal : "+bal);

        String sql1 = "UPDATE CUSTOMER SET Balance = ? WHERE Ac_No =?";
        ps = con.prepareStatement(sql1);
        ps.setInt(1,acNo);
        ps.setFloat(2,bal);
        int i = ps.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("New Balance updated.... "+i);
        System.out.println("Transaction Successful....");

        ps.close();
        con.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

}

sir..i am not getting the the Balance after while loop...and when i try to up-date it...it shows zero value for balance in console...while it is still contains that value what i inserted at first during creating a/c...
plz hlp me......[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7XTM.png)

[mysql workbench o/p](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t588A.png)

Comment: You have a local variable `bal` inside the loop, and probably a local field `bal` too. Also for the UPDATE: `ps.setInt(2, acNo);` and such.

Comment: so...what correction should i made in my cod eto get the correct o/p ////

Comment: but  i declarecd the "bal" as class variable in the program...and i am accessing it...so i think it may work as class level variable at evry point...

Comment: But in the loop you create a second `float bal`.

Comment: then what should i do for correct op..plz help

Answer (score 0):

Example code. Try-with-resources takes care of closing, even when an exception is thrown.

```
static class Customer {
    int acNo;
    String name;
    BigDecimal bal;
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("Enter your A/c no. : " );
    int acNo = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bank";
    try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "admin")) {
        Customer customer = loadCustomer(acNo);
        if (customer == null) {
            System.out.println("Wrong account");
        } else {
            System.out.printf("Current balance for %s, account %d: %12.2f%n",
                 customer.name, customer.acNo, customer.bal);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStacktrace();
    }
}

private static Customer loadCustomer(int accNo) throws SQLException {

    String sql = "SELECT Name, Balance FROM CUSTOMER WHERE Ac_No = ?";
    try (PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        ps.setInt(1, acNo);

        try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
             if (rs.next()) {
                 Customer customer = new Customer();
                 customer.acNo = acNo;
                 customer.name = rs.getString(1);
                 customer.bal = rs.getBigDecimal(2);
                 return customer;
             }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Enjoy programming